matlab script control over code in simulink matlab function block
I want to write a matlab script that creates a matlab function block in simulink and then writes the code into the block. Or, some equivalent of this. I can create the block using add_block(), and I can modify the code through the GUI. I can also use matlabFunctionBlock() to use symbolics to specify the function, but I cannot trust it as it converted sinc(x) to sin(pi x)/(pi x) and created a numerical fault. I don't want it to modify what I say - I want it to do exactly what I say. I can write sinc(x) into the block to fix this, so it is not a limitation of the block itself - only of the API.
As an answer, I would be fine with some method to use mex, fcn block, function block, and any of the various related blocks. But, I have not found anything that works. Can anyone give me a suggestion. I was expecting this to be a very basic operation - rather than a complicated deep dive into the inner workings of Simulink.

I have found out that the field to use is ...
config = get_param("model/block", "MATLABFunctionConfiguration");

and then to set
config.FunctionScript = "Script for function";

